# Does apigee-access works with express4

Tags: node.js, express, apigee

It seems that there is no way to make apigee-access to work with express v4, there is another question asking the same thing but is 10 months old, it seems that still doesn't work, i been working with apigee edge for aboutn 8 months now, and i feel that i don't see the point of using apigee-access if there is no compatibility with express, specially if you're making a some advanced things in your nodejs endpoint. Is there any other way to access and set flow vars from express/nodejs? Our make express work with apigee-access? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, [apigee-access](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apigee-access) works with express. I'm not sure what trouble you're having.

Here's some sample code that works for me:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var apigee = require('apigee-access');
var env = process.env;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/about", function(req, res, next) {
  var message = { "route" : 1 };
  message['path-in-apigee'] = apigee.getVariable(req, 'request.path') || "unknown";
  message['express-baseUrl'] = req.baseUrl;
  res.json(message);
});

// catch 404
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var payload = { message: "Not found" };
  res.status(404);
  res.json(payload);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT | 8124, function() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

I used express 4.12.3 and apigee-access 1.3.0.

When sending in this request:

```
curl -i http://ORGNAME-ENVNAME.apigee.net/proxy-pathsuffix/about
```

I get this response:

```
{
    "express-baseUrl": "/about",
    "path-in-apigee": "/proxy-pathsuffix/about",
    "route": 1
}
```

Note: the proxy base path is set like this in the proxies/default.xml:

```
<ProxyEndpoint name='default'>
  <Description>Default Proxy</Description>
  <HTTPProxyConnection>
    <BasePath>/proxy-pathsuffix</BasePath>
    <Properties/>
    <VirtualHost>default</VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost>secure</VirtualHost>
  </HTTPProxyConnection>
...
```

I suggest that you try [community.apigee.com](http://community.apigee.com) for more followups. It's pretty active.